# GCP routing issues from peered networks to common network which hosts VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

In my GCP environment an external network connects to a common services project via a HA VPN. This then connects to both development and production Shared VPC host projects via VPC Peering.

In both the Development and Production host projects there is Cloud NAT to allow outbound connections. This is actually only wanted for 1 domain.

All other traffic should route through the HA VPN tunnel which is advertising a destination IP range of 0.0.0.0/0 through BGP.

In trying to solve this I am coming up against a number of issues.

For Cloud NAT to work the default internet gateway has to be set to 0.0.0.0/0 which conflicts with the HA VPN broadcast. Also with Cloud NAT there is no way to set a domain, only an IP. I have also tried Secure Web Proxy and this seems to get me past the domain v IP issue but again I can't figure out a way to allow all other traffic through the HA VPN as my routes don't propagate into the Development and Production host projects through the VPC Network Peering. When I try to create a custom route in the common services project it is impossible for me to specify either of the VPN tunnels as the next hop as they simply don't show!